# Stop ids being added to headings in output in Middleman?

Tags: markdown, middleman

I'm using Markdown partials in my Middleman project - and just noticed that all my headings are being output with ids generated from the *heading markup*.

So for example a linked heading:

Markdown:

```
### [Useful reference sites](/webdev/useful-reference "Links to other sites")
```

Output html:

```
<h3 id="useful-reference-siteswebdevuseful-reference-links-to-other-sites">...</h3>
```

It's concatenating everything including contents of the anchor tag title attribute, so some ids can get ridiculously long.
I'd like to 'turn-off' this feature if possible.

I can't see anything in the core config list where I could do this, nor can I find info suggesting there's a helper for this kind of thing - but may be one exists?

In short, is there a way to do this without much ruby knowledge?

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Some info about the project set up:

- Middleman (3.3.7)
- extensions: middleman blog, nav-tree
- templates in Haml
- content partials in Markdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Middleman uses Kramdown for Markdown parsing.

The option that Kramdown uses to generate ids, [is](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html) `auto_ids`.

So what you have to do is to set that option to false in Middleman's `config.rb`:

```
set :markdown, auto_ids: false
```

Comment: Thanks so much, star! So glad it was a simple thing.